# error installing rpy2 on Mac

Tags: python, installation, rpy2

I am trying to install rpy2 on python 2.7.14, on a Mac OS High Sierra version 10.13.2, but when I try writing the command

`pip install rpy2`

I get the following output:

```
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached rpy2-2.9.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    rpy2 is no longer supporting Python < 3. Consider using an older rpy2 release when using an older Python release.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/11/xgl2d8l16wd8xv2_lmdtcmwc0000gn/T/pip-build-aJMHfU/rpy2/
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have already tried to upgrade the pip package by typing

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

but I get the following message:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I was able to install rpy2 on python3, but for some reason it is not installing on python2.

Here are the specifications from my python2:

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 12:01:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's stated that latest versions are only supported by python 3.

```
rpy2 is no longer supporting Python < 3. Consider using an older rpy2 release when using an older Python release.
```

If you really need to use python 2, try downloading the older version of rpy2 and [build it from source](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/overview.html#installation).

Answer (score 6):

Version 2.8.6 was the last version of rpy2 which supported the 2.x series of Python.

You can tell pip to install that version specifically:

```
pip install rpy2==2.8.6
```

<sub>Why a package manager - whose entire purpose in life is to handle dependency management - is not able to successfully figure this out on its own, I have no clue.</sub>